# Problema con peticiones en axios+react y json-server

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, frontend

quisiera saber cómo se pueden hacer dos peticiones a distintos endpoints en una misma función sin tener errores de CORS. Estoy trabajando con React, axios y json-server. Al momento de querer hacer una peticion POST en un endpoint (ej: http://localhost:3000/products) y al mismo tiempo un PUT en otro endpoint (ej: http://localhost:3000/stock) suponiendo que al agregar un producto debo modificar también el stock que tengo en el otro endpoint , obtengo el siguiente error:

Pedido de origen cruzado bloqueado: La política de mismo origen no permite leer el recurso remoto en http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/3. (Razón: el pedido de redireccionamiento externo no está permitido).

Pedido de origen cruzado bloqueado: La política de mismo origen no permite leer el recurso remoto en http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/3. (Razón: El pedido CORS falló). Código de estado: (null).

Si sólo hago una de las dos peticiones, funciona perfecto...

Agradezco su ayuda, saludos!

Comment: En que está desarrollada la api que lanza en localhost:3000?

Comment: Estoy utilizando react con axios y json-server. La app levanta en 3001 y el json-server en 3000 o cualquiera que yo elija, en todos los casos me aparece el mismo error. Intenté con el MOESIF CORS pero es lo mismo